# Java, Subclass return generics of generics

Tags: java, generics

Does anyone can tell me how to code the return in the function "getDirectHair()" ?
I want to create a method which is like a shortcut in the Human class to directly return the good type of Hair class (below named "h.getDirectHair()") instead of use "h.getPerson().getHair()".
I want to use the type <?> of Person<?> declared in Human class.

```
package test;
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Human<Bob> h = new Human<Bob>();
        Blond blond = h.getPerson().getHair(); // no cast needed, because Human<Bob> is blond
        //how to do if I want to use directly this :
        blond = (!!!) h.getDirectHair();  //need cast !! Blond or Brown ?
    }
}
class Human<T extends Person<?>>{
    private T person = null;
    public T getPerson() {
        return person;
    }
    public /* <?> */ Object getDirectHair(){
        // => I want to return the type <?> of Person<?> 
        // instead of Object, how to ??
        return person.getHair();
    }
}
class Person<T extends Hair> {
    T hair;
    public Person(T hairr) {
        hair = hairr;
    }
    public T getHair() {
        return hair;
    }
}
class Bob extends Person<Blond> {
    public Bob(Blond bean) {
        super(bean);
    }
    public Blond getHair() {
        return super.getHair();
    }
}
class Barack extends Person<Brown> {
    public Barack(Brown bean) {
        super(bean);
    }
    public Brown getHair() {
        return super.getHair();
    }
}
class Hair {
}
class Blond extends Hair {
}
class Brown extends Hair {
}
```

Many thanks and best regards,
David.

Comment: It's "heir", not "hair", BTW :).

Comment: @TheTerribleSwiftTomato: not if you read the examples

Comment: @TheTerribleSwiftTomato I assume Hair is correct, as getHair return Blond and Brown

Comment: @user2590746 why do you want to use generics for this? it seems like the ideal case of inheritance, Bob extends Person, Person extends Human, Human has getHair

Comment: Ah, my bad, read too quickly and assumed `getDirectHair()` is about inheritance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's how to fix the problem:

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Human<Blond, Bob> h = new Human<Blond, Bob>();
        Blond blond = h.getPerson().getHair(); 
        blond = h.getDirectHair();
    }
}

class Human<H extends Hair, T extends Person<H>>{
    private T person = null;
    public T getPerson() {
        return person;
    }
    public H getDirectHair(){
        return person.getHair();
    }
}
```

Comment: I guess in the existing heirarchy in the question it is not possible. Am I right?

Comment: The hierarchy in the question is preserved by my solution. The difference is that the Human class has an additional generic type H.

Comment: Then no, it's not possible. The type of the hair is unknown at compile time (`?`), so a cast is needed.

Comment: yes I think also this is the only solution, but it's like a double declaration: first `Human<Blond, Bob> h = new Human<Blond, Bob>();` and second `class Bob extends Person<Blond>`. The link between Bob and Blond is wrote twice. And if you need to do this for many variables, not so good.

Comment: +1 for the best answer you're going to get with Java generics.